# How many threads in Rake Multitask?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process, rake

I have a two Rake tasks I want to execute in parallel. They're both dependencies of a third task:

```
task :first_task do
  sleep 10
end

task :second_task do
  sleep 10
end

desc "execute two tasks in parallel"
multitask :third_task => [:first_task, :second_task] do
  puts "finished first one and second one!"
end
```

After running rake two_at_once, I executed pstree to see a process tree. I expected to see two processes spawned below the process executing "rake two_at_once," one for first_task and one for second_task. Instead, I see only one rake process:

[image]

Do I see only one process (even thought first_task and second_task are executing currently) because there multiple threads in the Ruby process 00640? If so, why does Rake use multiple threads rather than multiple processes?

Comment: Yes `Rake::Multitask` uses threads not processes -> https://ruby.github.io/rake/Rake/MultiTask.html